# how to get node id of xml file where some changed in xml child node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have XML file. I wants to get node id of XML file once it's changed contain of any node.

Example if i have XML file as bellow:

```
<servicestatuslist>
<servicestatus id='4693209'>
    <instance_id>1</instance_id>
    <service_id>6901</service_id>
    <host_id>5625</host_id>
    <host_name>host1</host_name>
    <name>battery_status</name>
</servicestatus>
<servicestatus id='4693200'>
    <instance_id>1</instance_id>
    <service_id>6901</service_id>
    <host_id>5625</host_id>
    <host_name>host2</host_name>
    <name>battery_status</name>
</servicestatus>
<servicestatus id='4693201'>
    <instance_id>1</instance_id>
    <service_id>6901</service_id>
    <host_id>5625</host_id>
    <host_name>host3</host_name>
    <name>battery_status</name>
</servicestatus>
</servicestatuslist>
```

Example: if "host_name" host1 changed to hostxxx then i can get  "servicestatus id" of changed node

Comment: How are you determining what's changing? And what have you tried so far - where's your code?

Comment: See the supported events of `XmlDocument` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_events(v=vs.110).aspx or `XDocument` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument_events(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: I am getting it by filewatcher class change event

Comment: Is there any solution?